# Android Camera2 API autofocus (AF) state remains in ACTIVE SCAN state

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2, autofocus

I'm stuck at the problem that after locking the android autofocus (AF) the AF state will change into AF_STATE_ACTIVE_SCAN and remain in that state forever. Restarting the AF trigger by cancel it and doing a restart doesn't work and will result in an infinite loop. How can I handle a state transition into another state so that the AF will focus correctly?

Heres my code of the CameraCaptureSession CaptureCallback and the lockFocus method which I'm using when starting the capture process and the unlockFocus method:

```
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mPreviewCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

        private void process(CaptureResult result) {
            switch (mCaptureState) {
                case STATE_PREVIEW:
                    // Do nothing
                    break;
                case STATE_WAIT_LOCK:
                    Integer afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
                    if (afState == null) {
                        startStillCaptureRequest();
                    } else if (CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState ||
                            CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState) {
                        Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                        if (aeState == null ||
                                aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                            mCaptureState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                            if (mFocusLockState == FOCUS_LOCK_STATE_TAKE_IMAGE) {
                                startStillCaptureRequest();
                            }
                            else{
                                unLockFocus();
                            }
                        } else {
                            runPrecaptureSequence();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE: {
                    Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                    if (aeState == null ||
                            aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE ||
                            aeState == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED) {
                        mCaptureState = STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE: {
                    Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                    if (aeState == null || aeState != CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE) {
                        mCaptureState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                        startStillCaptureRequest();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
            process(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCaptureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull CaptureFailure failure) {
            super.onCaptureFailed(session, request, failure);
            Log.e(TAG, "onCaptureFailed: Error capturing an image!");
        }
    };

private void lockFocus(int focusLockState) {
        mCaptureState = STATE_WAIT_LOCK;
        mFocusLockState = focusLockState;
        mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
        mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
        CaptureRequest captureRequest = mCaptureRequestBuilder.build();
        try {
                mPreviewCaptureSession.capture(captureRequest, mPreviewCaptureCallback, mCameraThreadHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void unLockFocus() {
        mCaptureState = STATE_PREVIEW;
        mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
        CaptureRequest captureRequest = mCaptureRequestBuilder.build();
        try {
                mPreviewCaptureSession.capture(captureRequest, null, mCameraThreadHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thanks,
AWSi-TS